# how to remove unused library code in java?

Tags: java, proguard, libraries

As the title says i want to remove not only unused libraries but also the unused code in the ones that are used.

For example i have a project where i use the javafx library only for the file chooser and doesn't want that 8mb unused code is siting in my project.

Ive tried using pro guard but i only manages to reduce the file size of my own code. Not the file size of the libraries.

Is there a tool for something like that or a setting in ProGuard I am missing.

Comment: Recommendations of alternate tools are generally [off-topic for stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource).  Regarding the specific question regarding potential pro-guard settings, I do not know that answer.  You might want to research [javafx runtime images in the openjfx docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), the information there may or may not assist you.

Comment: Consider the [shade plugin minimize-jar option](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#minimizeJar).

Comment: I think for somebody to answer, you might need to be far more specific about what you are doing (including build scripts, kind of deployment, e.g. native app, fat jar, etc). Consider if you really need to expend the effort to remove potential unused classes from libraries that you distribute. Understand that JavaFX is modular, so you don't need to include modules that you aren't using in your distribution (see the openjfx docs for info).